# SQLAlchemy : creating engine all the time affects performance?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I found some legacy codes that whenever sending a query, it gets current configuration from the current app and creates an engine from URI and then make a session. 
For example, if one API send like 9 queries, it creates engine nine times and makes sessions and then closes the session. 
I wonder if it affects performance because make engine multiple times looks inefficient since this application uses only two mysql databases (master and slave).

Comment: With postgres - noticed that creating an engine for each request was adding 30 to 35ms on the response time in a more real world scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) built in module to test things like this. For example:

```
C:\test> python -m timeit -u msec -s "from sqlalchemy import create_engine" "engine=create_engine('sqlite:///');engine.execute('SELECT 1')"
```

returns:

```
200 loops, best of 5: 1.21 msec per loop
```

and:

```
C:\test> python -m timeit -u msec -s "from sqlalchemy import create_engine;engine=create_engine('sqlite:///')" "engine.execute('SELECT 1')"
```

returns:

```
5000 loops, best of 5: 0.0371 msec per loop
```

Note that the difference between the two is in the second statement, the `engine=create_engine('sqlite:\\\')` statement is moved to the setup code.

So from this test, executing a sql statement from a globally defined engine is ~33x faster than building the engine for every statement issued.

Comment: One of the reasons is that an engine holds a pool of connections so that every time you need a connection you don't need to do all the handshaking etc. all over again, though in case of SQLite that's not even the case.